# Why are sunflower seeds so much smaller than their shells?

Tags: plant-physiology, seeds

I was snacking on some sunflower seeds recently when I noticed the large disparity between the size of the seed itself and the woody shell surrounding it. Why is this gap present? Is there some evolutionary advantage to making a seed pod larger? Or did the seed shrink over time?

Comment: I’m assuming the seeds you were eating were roasted and therefore dehydrated. Crack open a fresh seed and see if you observe the same thing.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh that would explain it. Thanks!